# Prestashop error: Shop context types other than Uncaught PrestaShopBundle

Tags: prestashop, context

Cuando hago una importación masiva de stock en la tienda me devuelve este error, ¿alguien sabe por qué? no entiendo porqué da error de contexto.

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught
> PrestaShopBundle\Exception\NotImplementedException: Shop context types
> other than "single shop" are not supported in
> /var/www/vhosts/midominio.com/httpdocs/src/PrestaShopBundle/Entity/Repository/StockManagementRepository.php:142